# What's faster...Loop or division?

Tags: c++, performance

What'll be faster in C++?

A loop or a division, considering that the size of the loop is comparable to the number of digits in the numbers being divided.

Comment: It can be done with one loop and no divisions.

Comment: And that is how?
A little hint will be enough.

Comment: -1 (Can be reverted) Writing meaningful titles.

Comment: I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does it with one loop and no divisions (uses C++11's range-based `for`, but can be easily rewritten to go without):

```
std::string s = "123";
int base = 10; // Must be <= 10, or the technique below won't work
int n = 0; for (char c : s) { n = n * base + (c - '0');  }
std::cout << n; // Should output 123
```

**EDIT:**

A safer, slightly more complex solution which will parse the string until a non-digit character is met:

```
#include <iostream>

int convert(std::string const& s, int base)
{
    int n = 0;
    for (char c : s)
    {
        if (!isdigit(c)) { break; }
        n = n * base + (c - '0');
    }

    return n;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s = "123d";
    cout << convert(s, 10) << endl; // Should output 123
}
```

Comment: You might want to hard-code `base`; it is somewhat misleading as it only works for `base <= 10`; anything above and 10 will be `:`, which isn't any number system I know.

Comment: @icktoofay: I just wanted to show `base` could be something different from 10, but you're right, this works only when it's `<= 10`. Will edit.

Comment: This solution is neat and it works well, but will cause weirdness when passed strings that contain non-numeric characters.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Yes, I'm aware of this. I just thought some demonstrative code was enough to answer. I've added a more elaborate version that does some checking on the input.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need two loops. You can do it in one, and as you are creating the integer, simply stop the loop when it reaches the end of the string. This is faster than both of the suggested solutions.

Comment: It was quite helpful. But my original question was what will be faster, a loop or a division. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Start with an initial number of zero. walk through each character from left to right in the string, multiply the number by 10, add the value of the current digit.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Horner's rule. I.e., in C, assuming the sting is only digits:

```
value = 0;
for(p = str; *p; p++)
   value = 10 * value + *p - '0';
```

One loop, no division.

Comment: I modified the question accordingly, since I wanted to know.if I use a loop or a division, what'll be faster?

Answer (score 0):

The division will take constant time (it is an instruction, after all), to compare that with looping through memory needs some measuring. A starting point to answering such questions is the [programs](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/appmodels.html) Jon Bentley cites in his "Programming pearls". The timing program needs a bit of massage to compile on current systems, and adjusting the output so it doesn't run together. And never forget that compilers are smart, often surprisingly so, before thinklking on mangling code for performance's sake.